# Unable to get ZF2 pagination

Tags: zend-framework2

I have written code in controller given below,

```
$iteratorAdapter  = new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator($this->getCategoryTable()->listCategoryData());
$paginatorDatas = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator($iteratorAdapter);
$paginatorDatas->setCurrentPageNumber($page)->setItemCountPerPage(5);
```

and I render the variable **$paginatorDatas** to view file.

In the corresponding view file, I have written the code like this,

```
echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginatorDatas, 'Elastic', 'paginator.phtml');
```

Before calling $this->paginationControl() function I have iterated the array object(**$paginatorDatas**), through `foreach(){}` to populate records.

But the above code gives the following error,

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after moving forward is not supported' in /var/www/cp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Result.php:153 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result->rewind() #1 /var/www/cp/module/Admin/view/admin/category/ajax-list.phtml(21): LimitIterator->rewind() #2 /var/www/cp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(507): include('/var/www/cp/mod...') #3 /var/www/cp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) #4 /var/www/cp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(102): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) #5 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #6 /var/www/cp/ in /var/www/cp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Result.php on line 153

Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
$resultSet = $this->getCategoryTable()->listCategoryData();
$resultSet->buffer();
$resultSet->next();
$iteratorAdapter  = new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator($resultSet);
$paginatorDatas = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator($iteratorAdapter);
$paginatorDatas->setCurrentPageNumber($page)->setItemCountPerPage(5);
```

From [this](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/zend-framework-2-zendpaginator-paginate-your-data/) tutorial from Samsonasik

**Method 2**

```
$resultSet = $this->getCategoryTable()->listCategoryData();
$resultSet = iterator_to_array($resultSet);
$adapter  = new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter($resultSet);
$paginatorDatas = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator($adapter);
$paginatorDatas->setCurrentPageNumber($page)->setItemCountPerPage(5);
```

Comment: @EKL Then, consider accepting and upvoting this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Populate an array with your query result and you can use an `\Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter` instead of `\Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator`

Comment: I tried this method, but still I am getting following error...

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter::__construct() must be an array, object given, called in /var/www/cp/module/Admin/src/Admin/Controller/CategoryController.php on line 74 and defined in /var/www/cp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Paginator/Adapter/ArrayAdapter.php on line 33

Comment: That is why i said POPULATE an array with your query result, not use it directly. ;)